# Insert from ELisp code using quail

Tags: insert

After evaluating the expressions in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarkgrubb/latex-input/master/latex.el) code, I evaluated `(activate-input-method "TeX")`. When I type in the buffer \`a, the translation happens as expected and I get `à`. However, I cannot achieve the same effect by `insert`:

```
(insert "\\`a")
```

The result is: \`a

I tried a sequence of inserts without success:

```
(progn (insert "\\") (insert "`") (insert "a") (insert " "))
```

The result is: \`a

So, how can I insert a string in a way that it gets translated?

Comment: I once tried to do that and ended up using keyboard macros to achieve the effect. But what are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing but this inserts something `(insert (quail-lookup-map-and-concat (kbd "\\\`a")))`